# How to safely delete local git branches?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have build up a bunch of local branches.  I want to safely get rid of them.  By safely, I mean I would like to only delete the local branches for the remotes have been merged and deleted.

I used gitlab to delete merged branches, however that leaves the local branches.  I tried pruning, but it didn't seem to do what I expected.

I ran `git branch -vv`

```
  Branch_XYZ   82142af1 [origin/Branch_XYZ: gone] Some commit message
  Branch_XYZ2   82142af1 [origin/Branch_XYZ2: gone] Some commit message
  ...
```

I *think* all these ones are safe to delete, but I would like git to do it for all of them.  I have like 30 or something. (Spring Cleaning Time)

GC

Comment: If those branches have been merged in the remote repo, you just need to prune the tracking branches then.

Comment: @JeffMercado Pruning just removes the reference to the remove branch or some useless junkn like that, not actually remove the local branch,

Comment: Sorry, misread what I was seeing, didn't know git can list local branches and point out that the tracking branch is gone. Thought you were showing all tracking branches.

Comment: @JeffMercado Pruning is silly, I not sure what it does, maybe it prunes remote branches, but not local.

Comment: It removes the remote branches (`refs/remotes/**`) if the corresponding branch on the remote is deleted. Remote branches are separate from local branches and keeps track of what your local repo understands is on the remote.